# 404 Error in "Writing your first Django App" tutorial

Tags: python, django

I am new to programming and have been working through the "Writing your first Django App" Tutorial for version 1.8.  I'm stuck with an error.

```
Page not found (404)
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://localhost:8000/polls
Using the URLconf defined in mysite.urls, Django tried these URL patterns, in this order:
^admin/
The current URL, polls, didn't match any of these.
```

I've seen others with a similar error but did not see a resolution.  I even went so far as to simply copy and paste what is in the tutorial for the files in this section (the top part of section 3) but still haven't seen a resolution.

Mysite\polls\urls.py

```
from django.conf.urls import url

from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', views.index, name='index'),
]
```

Mysite\urls.py

```
from django.conf.urls import include, url
from django.contrib import admin

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^polls/', include('polls.urls')),
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
]
```

Mysite\polls\views.py

```
from django.http import HttpResponse


def index(request):
    return HttpResponse("Hello, world. You're at the polls index.")
```

Mysite\settings.py

```
...
INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'polls',
)

MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.SessionAuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
)

ROOT_URLCONF = 'mysite.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates')],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'mysite.wsgi.application'
...
```

I have no idea where the disconnect is but my guess based on the error is that it is with the urls.py file in the main mysite directory... it doesn't seem to read the urlpatterns for polls?  How could this be resolvd? (I should note I tried this with and without the final "/" after polls for the url in the browser).

Comment: Does it works if you go admin default url `http://localhost:8000/admin` ?

Comment: Try doing the import: `from polls import urls as polls_urls` and then `url(r'^polls/', include(polls_urls))`

Answer (score 20):

The root urls should be at `mysite\mysite\urls.py`, not `mysite\urls.py` as you have it.

Comment: Yes there is a seperate one there... and this is that file.

from django.conf.urls import include, url
from django.contrib import admin

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
]

Comment: You need to include the `polls.urls` in `mysite/mysite/urls.py`. Remove the other `mysite/urls.py`, it isn't used by Django so is just confusing things.

Comment: That worked.  I must have read the tutorial wrong on where to place that URLS file.  Thank you so much!

Comment: Don't worry about it - easy mistake to make. At least your question was very clear so it was easy to spot the problem :)

Comment: This got me too.  Thank you @Alasdair.

Comment: @Alasdair  Bless you for your comment. Saved me from giving up!