# Django poll app tutorial is not working as expected in my server

Tags: django

i am cuurently working on django poll app tutorial and i am getting this error .

```
Using the URLconf defined in mysite.urls, Django tried these URL patterns, in this order:

polls/
admin/
The empty path didn't match any of these.
```

already tried restarting the server ,migrate the data and settings.py having installed apps . however django tutorial doesnot ask you for this until now.
working on windows 10 64 bit

polls/urls.py

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views
urlpatterns=[path('',views.index,name='index'),]
```

mysite/urls.py

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import include,path
urlpatterns=[path('polls/',include('polls.urls')),path('admin/',admin.site.urls')),]
```

results should be response from the views.py file

Comment: Can you explain what doesn't work? Can you provide screenshot of browser?

Comment: You didn't read the tutorial properly. There's even a specific prompt for the issue you're having, complete with a green box to highlight it: "Page not found?
If you get an error page here, check that you’re going to `http://localhost:8000/polls/` and not `http://localhost:8000/`."

Comment: Also note that it has / at the end, so you have to go to [localhost:8000/polls/](http://localhost:8000/polls/)

Comment: I'll answer after 40 minutes, i have to go for a while now

Comment: i tried polls/ too and it still says the same and do not return the index functions request

Answer (score 2):

I had this problem when I put the urls.py by mistake in the upper mysite/ upper root folder, to solve it just move the urls.py file inside mysite/mysite/ path
as the root folder structure is like this:

```
mysite/ (don't put urls.py inside this one!)
    manage.py
    mysite/ (put it inside here!)
        __init__.py
        settings.py
        urls.py
        asgi.py
        wsgi.py
    polls/
        __init__.py
        admin.py
        apps.py
        migrations/
            __init__.py
        models.py
        tests.py
        views.py
```

please check this answer as it looks like a duplicate of the same problem

[404 Error in "Writing your first Django App" tutorial](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30493018/404-error-in-writing-your-first-django-app-tutorial?rq=1)

Answer (score 0):

I think everything with your code is ok. But you are propapbly visiting "localhost:8000" instead of "localhost:8000/polls".

If you want to work on polls app on root URL, you need to edit your code this way:

mysite/urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('', include('app.urls')),
]
```

polls/urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.index, name='index')),
]
```

I think also you have to make your code more clear, too look more readable for everyone (for you too!)

Comment: I will edit this answer after short while to show you how to make polls on localhost:8000

Comment: Hi I have exactly the same content in my files but I still get an error while starting the server `raise ImproperlyConfigured(msg.format(name=self.urlconf_name)) from e
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: The included URLconf '<module 'polls.urls' from '/home/mahmood/Desktop/ImagesStack/polls/urls.py'>' does not appear to have any patterns in it. If you see the 'urlpatterns' variable with valid patterns in the file then the issue is probably caused by a circular import.`

Answer (score 0):

Your code is ok , you are trying to access a url that you never mentioned in the mysite/urls.py.

Change url pattern in msysite/urls.py to the following to access the polls app 127.0.0.1:8000/

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import include,path
urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('',include('polls.urls')),

]
```

And in polls/urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.index, name='index'),
]
```

NOTE: The urlpattern you tried will work at http://127.0.0.1:8000/polls/
Since you used following code in mysite/urls.py

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import include,path
urlpatterns = [
path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
path('polls/',include('polls.urls')),
]
```